# Unable to build entity manager factory em jar criado com maven

Tags: java, maven, jar

Bom dia pessoal,

Em um projeto estamos usando Hibernate, Log4J2, Gson e algumas outras coisas que vocês podem ver no pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>br.org.minhaempresa</groupId>
<artifactId>meuprojeto</artifactId>
<name>meuprojeto</name>

<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<organization>
    <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
    <name>***</name>
</organization>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>

    <finalName>meuprojeto</finalName>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.5</version>
            <configuration>

                            <mainClass>br.org.minhaempresa.meuprojeto.MainApp</mainClass>

                <!-- only required if signing the jar file -->
                <keyStoreAlias>example-user</keyStoreAlias>
                <keyStorePassword>example-password</keyStorePassword>
                <allPermissions>true</allPermissions>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                <checkModificationExcludes>
                    <checkModificationExclude>pom.xml</checkModificationExclude>
                </checkModificationExcludes>
                <tagNameFormat>version-@{project.version}</tagNameFormat>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>br.org.minhaempresa.meuprojeto.MainApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>${project.build.finalName}-${project.version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>

    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Impinj OctaneSDK -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.impinj</groupId>
        <artifactId>octanesdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.22.0.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Pi4j dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pi4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>pi4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL Connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- UaiCriteria -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>uaihebert.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>uaiCriteria</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Gson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- PDFBox -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache Commons lang -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Ao executar o programa através do Run as Java Application, tudo funciona adequadamente, conectando ao meu banco de dados. Ai eu gero o jar com todas as dependências(meuprograma-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies). Ao executar a aplicação com *java -jar meuprograma-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar* a aplicação não conecta no banco de dados e me retorna a seguinte mensagem:

```
Unable to build entity manager factory
```

Eu abri o jar para ver se o persistence.xml está lá dentro. Está! Dentro do projeto ele está na pasta src/main/resources/META-INF.

Meu persistence.xml. As propriedades estão na classe de conexão:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<persistence-unit name="crp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
public class Conexao {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MainApp");
private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public Conexao() throws Exception{

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    props.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect");

    props.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
    props.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");

    props.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment", 2);
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.min_size", 2);
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_size", 10);
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", 50);
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.timeout", 0);
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", 3000);
    props.put("hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout", 15000);
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_crp");
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "user");
    props.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "pass");

    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("crp", props);

}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() throws Exception {
    //responsavel pela persistencia
    if (emf != null)
        return emf.createEntityManager();

    return null;
}

public void close() {

    if (emf != null){
        emf.close();
        logger.info("Fechando conexão com BD...");
    }
}
```

}

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo?

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Coloca o código do teu persistence.xml.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra editei minha questão com essas informações.

Comment: Se quando você executa como java Application funciona tudo normalmente no jar também deveria funcionar. Provavelmente deve ter faltado alguma coisa na montagem do jar. Talvez esteja faltando algum classpath no MANIFEST.mf. Como esse .jar está sendo montado?

Comment: @SérgioMucciaccia executo mvn package e o jar com as depenências é gerado. Não sabia sobre o MANIFEST.mf. Ele deve ser criado automaticamente pelo Maven ou eu preciso criá-lo?

Comment: Ele é criado automaticamente pelo Maven, mas seria bom verificar se as dependências estão todas certinho dentro do .jar. Você está usando qual ide? No eclipse tem um plugin pra isso (export > java > runnable jar file), talvez seja mais fácil que fazer diretamente pelo mvn.

Comment: Estranho demais! Você está usando o package do maven corretamente, inclusive eu uso sempre dessa forma e funciona. Eu sugiro que você pegue esse jar with dependencies gerado e veja se no conteúdo dele todas as dependências foram de fato empacotadas. Infelizmente não vejo uma forma mais simples de depurar isso =/